# Code Alignment In SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, text-alignment

I am using SQL Server Management Studio.I want to know the shortcuts for easily aligning the T-SQL Queries similiar to ctrl+k+d in visual studio.

Comment: Oracle's SQL Developer had a function called "beautifier" - only thing that gave it grief was WITH syntax.  I miss developing in PLSQL... :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, you can only use 3rd party tools such as [SSMS Tools Pack](http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/) (free) or [Red Gate stuff](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Refactor/index.htm) (not free)

Answer (score 1):

```
CTRL-SHIFT-F2         -- Clear all bookmarks. 
CTRL+F2               -- Insert or remove a bookmark (toggle). 
F2                    -- Move to next bookmark. 
SHIFT+F2              -- Move to previous bookmark. 
ALT+BREAK             -- Cancel a query. 
CTRL+O                -- Connect. 
CTRL+F4               -- Disconnect. 
CTRL+F4               -- Disconnect and close child window. 
ALT+F1                -- Database object information. 
CTRL+SHIFT+DEL        -- Clear the active Editor pane. 
CTRL+SHIFT+C          -- Comment out code. 
CTRL+C or Ctrl+Insert -- Copy
CTRL+X or Shift+Del   -- Cut
SHIFT+TAB             -- Decrease indent. 
CTRL+DEL              -- Delete through the end of a line in the Editor pane. 
CTRL+F                -- Find. 
CTRL+G                -- Go to a line number. 
TAB                   -- Increase indent. 
CTRL+SHIFT+L          -- Make selection lowercase. 
CTRL+SHIFT+U          -- Make selection uppercase. 
CTRL+V or Shift+Insert-- Paste. 
CTRL+SHIFT+R          -- Remove comments. 
F3                    -- Repeat last search or find next. 
CTRL+H                -- Replace. 
CTRL+A                -- Select all. 
CTRL+Z                -- Undo. 
F5 or Ctrl + E        -- Execute a query. 
F1                    -- Help for Query Analyzer. 
SHIFT+F1              -- Help for the selected Transact-SQL statement. 
F6                    -- Switch between query and result panes. 
Shift+F6              -- Switch panes. 
CTRL+W                -- Window Selector. 
CTRL+N                -- New Query window. 
F8                    -- Object Browser (show/hide). 
F4                    -- Object Search. 
CTRL+F5               -- Parse the query and check syntax. 
CTRL+P                -- Print
CTRL+D                -- Display results in grid format. 
CTRL+T                -- Display results in text format. 
CTRL+B                -- Move the splitter. 
CTRL+SHIFT+F          -- Save results to file. 
CTRL+R                -- Show Results pane (toggle). 
CTRL+S                -- Save
CTRL+SHIFT+INSERT     -- Insert a template. 
CTRL+SHIFT+M          -- Replace template parameters. 
CTRL+L                -- Display estimated execution plan. 
CTRL+K                -- Display execution plan (toggle ON/OFF). 
CTRL+I                -- Index Tuning Wizard. 
CTRL+SHIFT+S          -- Show client statistics 
CTRL+SHIFT+T          -- Show server trace. 
CTRL+U                -- Use database
```

Comment: Pay more attention to formatting when posting.  Your post was unreadable.

Comment: Also most of those shortcuts are not relevant to the question.  Perhaps all.